# Issue creating app package for windows 8.1 metro app using the visual studio wizard.

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, sideloading, appx

I have tried the following steps (as outlined on MSDN):

1. Select the project in solution explorer.
2. Go to Project > Store > Create App Packages
3. Select No as the application does not need to be uploaded to the Windows Store.
4. Click Next and then Create.

I receive the following error in my output window:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3952,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file

"C:\Projects\MyProject\bin\x64\Debug\MyProject_1.0.0.0_x64_Debug.appx" to 
"obj\x64\Debug\MyProject_1.0.0.0_Bundle\MyProject_1.0.0.0_x64_Debug.appx".

Access to the path 'C:\Projects\MyProject\bin\x64\Debug\MyProject_1.0.0.0_x64_Debug.appx' is denied.

If I navigate to the folder obj\x64\Debug and find the generated .appx file I see that there are no permissions defined for the file? Why is this happening?

I have tried to run Visual Studio as an administrator but still receiving the same error.

Comment: maybe your used AV suite blocks it.

Comment: Tried disabling it but still having issues.

Comment: Seems like a similar issue has been posted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8bee78fd-6b32-4c44-a884-c89f9c900f24/create-app-package-bundle-creation-failed-access-is-denied?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: have you tried the answer and gave your account full access to the appx file?

Comment: Yes I have tried that.... the problem is it is trying to copy it from one location to another.